# NSTableCellView ImageView is null

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, xamarin.mac, nsimageview

I use simple 
 **NSTableViewDelegate** , inside **GetViewForItem** method I find with with Identifier

```
NSTableCellView view = (NSTableCellView)tableView.MakeView (tableColumn.Identifier, this);
```

If Identifier is "Img"  view should contain ImageView :

```
switch (tableColumn.Identifier) {
                case "Img":
                    var imageData = DataSource.Patients [(int)row].getImageData ();
                    if (imageData != null) {
                        view.ImageView.Image = new NSImage (imageData);
                    } else {
                        view.ImageView.Image = NSImage.ImageNamed ("client.png");
                    }
                    tableColumn.HeaderCell.BackgroundStyle = NSBackgroundStyle.Dark;
                    break;
                }
```

but **view.ImageView is null**

here is screenshot from xcode, how Img cell looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you connect the ImageView to the Table Cell View imageView outlet in xcode?

Click/select the Table Cell View. In the properties panel select the outlets tab (the one with the arrow to the right in a circle). Drag the little circle behind the imageView outlet to your imageview and release.

Comment: one more question @svn, I need to connect action to this image view, I added action in xcode, but it is not called. do you have any idea?

Comment: image view does not support click action (use NSButton for that). It does support an action when a user drags an image on to if (if the imageview is set to editable). Never used this thought. 

I never use actions in xcode. But always subscribe to an event on the control in c#. For the default action this is the Activated event.

Comment: yeap, it works... here is my new question, if you can write answer